# Tomorrow then. let's see what happens

Tags: punctuation

> **Tomorrow then. Let's see what happens.**

How would this be punctuated?

Comment: My own merely personal preference would be for “Tomorrow, then—let’s see what happens.”

Comment: You would put a period at the end of the second sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this a few different ways:

- Tomorrow, then; let's see what happens.
- Tomorrow, then, let's see what happens.
- Tomorrow, then. Let's see what happens.
- Tomorrow, then—let's see what happens.

It really just depends on preference and sometimes the context.

Comment: No comma before *then* with any of these?

Comment: Oh, oops, yes, there is. I was just looking at what the OP posted, and I didn't get much sleep last night. I'll fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A brief check in the Ngram viewer finds published examples with and without a comma.  So "Tomorrow, then." or "Tomorrow then."  This phrase appears in dialog, so it's up to you to decide whether the pause between the two words is long enough to warrant punctuation.

Comment: English is long accustomed to using commas that do not reflect any pauses in oral discourse but just clarify syntax. That is why in *A Midsummer Night's Dream* pretty much all modern  texts have "Speak, Pyramus. Thisbe, stand forth" even though Q1 shows "Speake *Pyramus: Thyſby* ſtand forth" (arguably omitting the commas because proper oral performance would admit no pauses in those two places).